# Cannot output String with returned double

Tags: java

Below is a program, that I am having difficulty outputting the String message with the returned double values. Any help is greatly appreciated I am not sure where to go from here. I am probably over-thinking it or over-seeing a simple solution. Thankyou! I am unable to change Test2 in anyway.

The expected output is:

```
average = 12.5  
average = 7.63  
average = 6.96
```

however my program is outputting:

```
12.5  
7.63  
6.96
```

Here is my code:

```
class Test2{
       public static void main(String[] args){
          int i, j;  
          double di, dj, dk;  
          i = 20;  
          j = 5;  
          Overload ol = new Overload();  
          System.out.println(ol.findAverage(i, j));  
          di = 14.29;  
          dj = 0.97;  
          System.out.println(ol.findAverage(di, dj));  
          di = 3.51;  
          dj = 13.5;  
          dk = 3.87;  
          System.out.println(ol.findAverage(di, dj, dk));
       }
    }

    class Overload {
       private int i, j;
       private double di, dj, dk;
       private double average;

       public double findAverage(int i, int j) {
          average = ((i + j) / 2.0);    
          return average;
       } 

       public double findAverage(double di, double dj) { 
          average = (di + dj) / 2.0; 
          return average;
       } 

       public double findAverage(double di, double dj, double dk) { 
          average = (di + dj + dk) / 3.0; 
          return average;
       }

       public String findAverage() {
          return "average = " + average;
       }
    }
```

Comment: It is called in the main method

Comment: System.out.println("average = "+ol.findAverage(i, j));

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt the overloaded versions, yes, the one to print, no

Comment: I see what you mean now, my bad.

Comment: What dvsakgec said. You can just concatenate strings like this: `"aa" + "bb"`. If one of the operands is not a string, then it is first converted to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it like

```
       public String findAverage(double di, double dj, double dk) { 
          average = (di + dj + dk) / 3.0; 
          return returnAverage();
       }

       public String returnAverage() {
          return "average = " + average;
       }
```

You can modify other two overloaded methods in similar manner.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, I think I just got caught up in returning a double value and didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `public double findAverage(int i, int j)` method signature to `public String findAverage(int i, int j)` and `return "average = " + average;`

Similarly make changes in other methods.